# Odoo 13 how to validate a delivery order with API (python)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to make Odoo delivery orders as validated with the API.

Similar to this [How to validate a Odoo delivery order with XMLRPC PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260762/how-to-validate-a-odoo-delivery-order-with-xmlrpc-php) Note this is in PHP.

```
    close_order = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
                                'stock.move', 'search',
                                [[['origin', '=', 'S0032']]],
                                )
print(close_order)


so_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.move', 'write', [close_order, {
    'state': 'done'
}])
```

This searches for the stock move and marks it as done. But the products are still marked as reserved. How can I mark the delivery orders as validated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. For those having similar issues. I had to `create` then `process` `stock.immediate.transfer` to validate the stock move.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/stock/wizard/stock_immediate_transfer.py#L14

Answer (score 0):

hedgethenight

With change, the **state** will not do the background process to validate the `stock.move`.
You have to execute the method which can be processed to `done` the `stock.move`.

How to Execute the method from [XML-RPC](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html)

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'object', 'method', [[id]])
```

Comment: So calling the done method from stock.move doesn't work because it doesn't exist.  Do you by any chance know the method for validating the move? Not able to find it the documentation for v13